# How do we changeline in a label?

Tags: java, string, jlabel

I have a label and when setting the text I want to change line .
For instance

```
String str="first line \n Secondline ";
JLabel label.setText(str);
```

I tried the above code but it does not work..How do I change line in a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing does not uses classical line breaks. Instead, for a reason I never fully understood, [it uses HTML 3.2](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JLabel.html).
As a consequence, to have your text correctly displayed, yopu have to rely upon HTML content :

```
String str= "<html>First line<br>Second line</html>"
```

However, if you really want to, there are other [possibilities](http://codeguru.earthweb.com/java/articles/198.shtml) ...

Answer (score 2):

Use this string

```
String str= "<html>First line<br>Second line</html>"
```