# How do we changeline in a label?

Tags: java, string, swing, jlabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we changeline in a label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546204/how-do-we-changeline-in-a-label)

I have a label and when setting the text I want to change line .
For instance

```
String str="first line \n Secondline ";
JLabel label.setText(str);
```

I tried the above code but it does not work..How do I change line in a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use html formatting! :)

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>first line<br>second line</html>");
```

You can do all kinds of stuff with it; making text bold, sizing, drawing images etc..!